# MYSQL Update from within same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some data that has gone wrong, that I need to fix up.  Below is an example:

```
TABLE-A
id, type, value
1, 10, 123456
2, 10, NULL
3, 10, NULL
4, 20, 123456
5, 20, 654321
6, 20, NULL
```

I need a MYSQL update command.

If the "type" is the same then update the "value" so it is the same as long as the value is NULL and the "value" is unique

`UPDATE table-a SET value = (...)`

So in the table above only `id 2` and `3` will have the value updated to 123456

`id 6` will not update as the "value" is not unique for the the same "type".

Comment: what should be value of "id"6 in above example as it can be updated to either 123456 or 654321?

Comment: It should not be updated, I will have to manually update these.

Comment: I would not suggest you do it in a single query.A single query can be complex.Use PHP or some other language,you are working with.

Comment: I am using PHP, but cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A t
         JOIN
           ( SELECT type
                  , MIN(value) AS value
             FROM TABLE_A
             GROUP BY type
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 1
           ) AS tu
         ON tu.type = t.type
SET t.value = tu.value
WHERE t.value IS NULL
```

As Peufeu pointed, the `DISTINCT` is needed to catch cases like this one, where I suppose the id=3 row has to be updated, too:

```
TABLE-A
id | type | value
 1 |  10  | 123456
 2 |  10  | 123456
 3 |  10  | NULL
 4 |  20  | 123456
 5 |  20  | 654321
 6 |  20  | NULL
```

Comment: count(value) is wrong here : you meant count(DISTINCT value) I guess.

Comment: @peufeu: Yeah, I guess `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` is more correct. It will catch cases where for a type there are two or more rows with exact same value and all other rows are NULL. Thnx.

Comment: works well for my example, thanks.  however if the table has 7,30,123456  8,30,123456  9,30,NULL then ID 9 does not update