# Checking if a value in a column is present in a column of another table

Tags: mysql

I have 
`TABLE1 with COLUMNS A,B,...` and want to check if values of COLUMN A are in some other list e.g. column X in TABLE2. The result should be column C in TABLE 1 (Boolean TRUE, FALSE)

Is there some elegant way how to do this? What I am doing now is `SELECT +LEFT JOIN` into a new table(CREATE TABLE X SELECT...). Is there some possibility to do `UPDATE TABLE1 SET C =....` So no other table but only the old TABLE1.

thank you

Comment: Checkout this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556421/mysql-update-from-within-same-table it's shows how to do a join in an Update

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.X = t1.A
SET       t1.C = (CASE WHEN t2.X IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END);
```